# Is there a word for the moment before something irreversible happens?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine you are about to do something that will impact you greatly, for better or worse. is there a word that captures the feeling, of being at the cusp of a great event that is not necessarily good or bad?

Comment: There are quite a few ... what has your research revealed?

Comment: _Momentous_ itself is defined as 
<< of great importance or significance, especially in having a bearing on future events.
"_a period of momentous changes in East–West relations_" >> [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/momentous)]

Comment: There are probably many credible alternatives, depending on the *exact* context & intended meaning, so I think this is POB. My suggestion: ***...when it comes to the crunch***.

Comment: From the SWR tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. "

Answer (score 2):

If we are going for an individual word I like **watershed**.
For example in the sentence "It was a watershed moment in her life."

You could also try **brink**, **milestone**, **turning-point**, **advent** or your word **cusp** seems good.